# Laravel 5.5 Multi Authentication Routing Issue

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, routes

Trying to get Laravel multiple authentication to work using Doctrine instead of Eloquent. I've tried multiple things but keep getting stuck. I currently have two guards defined, two models, two login controllers, etc. If I enable either one or the other, they work. If I try both at the same time, only the default guard seems to work. When I try to access the other guard, I get redirected to the wrong login page.

If I go to /login - works as expected

If I go to /home (without being logged in) - redirected to /login as expected

If I go to /register- works as expected

If I go to /admin/login - works as expected

If I go to /admin/register - works as expected

If I go to /admin (without being logged in) - fail - should get redirected to /admin/login but instead getting redirected to /login

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Everything works individually. It's just getting the /admin route to use the right middleware...I think...maybe?

My routes file:

```
Auth::routes();

// staff authentication routes
Route::group( [ 'middleware' => [ 'web' ] ], function() {
  Route::get( 'admin/login', 'Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm' );
  Route::post( 'admin/login', [ 'as' => 'staff.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffLoginController@login' ] );
  Route::get( 'admin/register', 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@showRegistrationForm' );
  Route::post( 'admin/register', [ 'as' => 'staff.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@register' ] );

  Route::group( [ 'middleware' => [ 'staff' ] ], function() {
    Route::get( '/admin', 'AdminController@index' )->name( 'admin' );
  });
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I've tried various route definitions but this is the latest iteration. None of the previous iterations worked either.

My auth file:

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'staff' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'adminusers',
    ]
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'doctrine',
        'model' => App\Users\Customer::class,
    ],
    'adminusers' => [
        'driver' => 'doctrine',
        'model' => App\Users\Staff::class,
    ]
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'adminusers' => [
        'provider' => 'adminusers',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 30,
    ],
],
```

My LoginController (basically same as out of the box):

```
class LoginController extends Controller {
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  protected $redirectTo = '/home';

  public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  }
}
```

My StaffLoginController:

```
<?php

class StaffLoginController extends Controller {
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  protected $redirectTo = '/admin';

  protected $guard = 'staff';

  public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware( 'guest' )->except( 'logout' );
  }

  public function showLoginForm() {
    return view( 'auth.staff.login' );
  }

  public function login( Request $request ) {
    $this->validate( $request, [
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if( auth()->guard( 'staff' )->attempt( [
      'email' => $request->input( 'email' ),
      'password' => $request->input( 'password' ),
    ])) {
      return view( 'staff' );
    } else {
      return view( 'auth.staff.login' )->withErrors( [ 'email' => 'Authentication failed' ] );
    }
  }

  protected function guard() {
    return \Auth::guard( 'staff' );
  }
}
```

My AdminController:

```
class AdminController extends Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware( 'auth:staff' );
  }

  public function index() {
    return view( 'staff' );
  }
}
```

My RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated middleware (which is registered in Http\Kernel.php routeMiddleware as 'staff' => \SNJ\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated::class, ):

```
class RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated {
  public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = 'staff' ) {
    if ( !Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {
      return view( 'auth.staff.login' );
    }

    return $next( $request );
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

Changed routes in web.php to be as thus (removed the middleware from the admin/login and admin/register routes:

```
Auth::routes();

// staff authentication routes
Route::get( 'admin/login', 'Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm' );
Route::post( 'admin/login', [ 'as' => 'staff.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffLoginController@login' ] );
Route::get( 'admin/register', 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@showRegistrationForm' );
Route::post( 'admin/register', [ 'as' => 'staff.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@register' ] );

Route::group( [ 'middleware' => [ 'staff' ] ], function() {
  Route::get( '/admin', 'AdminController@index' )->name( 'admin' );
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

No change. Still doesn't work.

Tried changing routes thusly (put all admin routes into 'staff' middleware:
    Auth::routes();

```
// staff authentication routes

Route::group( [ 'middleware' => [ 'staff' ] ], function() {
  Route::get( 'admin/login', 'Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm' );
  Route::post( 'admin/login', [ 'as' => 'staff.login', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffLoginController@login' ] );
  Route::get( 'admin/register', 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@showRegistrationForm' );
  Route::post( 'admin/register', [ 'as' => 'staff.register', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@register' ] );
  Route::get( '/admin', 'AdminController@index' )->name( 'admin' );
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Same same. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `StaffLoginController` to this,

```
    <?php

class StaffLoginController extends Controller {
  use AuthenticatesUsers;

  public function showLoginForm() {
    return view( 'auth.staff.login' );
  }

  public function login( Request $request ) {
    $this->validate( $request, [
      'email' => 'required|email',
      'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if( auth()->guard( 'staff' )->attempt( [
      'email' => $request->input( 'email' ),
      'password' => $request->input( 'password' ),
    ])) {
      return view( 'staff' );
    } else {
      return view( 'auth.staff.login' )->withErrors( [ 'email' => 'Authentication failed' ] );
    }
  }
}
```

remove constructor from AdminController, we are later going to call this middleware on routes.

```
class AdminController extends Controller {

  public function index() {
    return view( 'staff' );
  }
}
```

You don't need to pass the guard value to auth middleware since you already defined as second middleware for authenticating `admin` routes.

update your staff middleware like this.

```
class RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated {
  public function handle( $request, Closure $next, $guard = null ) {
    if ( Auth::guard( $guard )->check() ) {

if(! $guard == 'staff')
                {
                    return redirect()->route( 'staff.login.form' ); 
                }
     }else return redirect()->route( 'staff.login.form' ); 

    return $next( $request );
  }
}
```

Now update your routes.

```
Route::get( 'admin/login', 'Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm' );
Route::post( 'admin/login', [ 'as' => 'staff.login.submit', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffLoginController@login' ] );
Route::get( 'admin/register', 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@showRegistrationForm' );
Route::post( 'admin/register', [ 'as' => 'staff.register.submit', 'uses' => 'Auth\StaffRegisterController@register' ] );
Route::group( [ 'middleware' => [ 'staff' ] ], function() {
  Route::get( '/admin', 'AdminController@index' )->name( 'admin' );
});
```

Also add the following lines to your `unauthenticated` function in  `Handler.php` file in `app\Exceptions`

```
$guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
        switch ($guard) {
      case 'staff':
        $login = 'admin/login';
        break;
    case 'users':
        $login = 'login';
        break;
      default:
        $login = 'login';
        break;
    }
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

Please check your `app/Kernel.php`, you can see that `guest` is an alias for `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` middleware.

You don't need to call constructors on both `web.php` file and on the controllers constructor.

Here the `RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated` middleware checks the root `/admin` is authenticated and it has a guard value of `staff`, if not it will redirect to the `/admin/login` route.

Please read [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users)  for clarification

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried removing that from the Controller. I still end up redirected to /login instead of /admin/login.

Comment: I also tried changing that line to $this->middleware( 'staff' ) but that had the same effect. I still end up at /login

Comment: Your staff register and login routes still use web middleware, try to separate them from web middleware in the web.php file

Comment: Tried that. A couple different ways (I updated the original post with what I tried). Still no luck.

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Thanks! It works with a couple minor changes. In the RedirectIfStaffUnauthenticated middleware class, returning a view causes a fatal error ( which I found the answer to here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fatalthrowableerror-in-verifycsrftokenphp-line-135-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setcookie-on-null ) so I added changed the route in web.php to be Route::get( 'admin/login', 'Auth\StaffLoginController@showLoginForm' )->name( 'staff.login.form' ); and I changed the redirects in the middleware to be return redirect( route( 'staff.login.form' ) );

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)