# Laravel Multi-Auth Routing issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When i install multi-auth in laravel but routing issue occur.

I'm edit in web.php when address bar write in ,

```
localhost/projectname/admin
```

but error occur - page not found
but i passed specific address like this

```
localhost/projectname/admin/login
```

after that page open BUT this not good.
can you possible i'm only pass

```
localhost/projectname/admin
```

after that page(view) open ?

Middleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotAdmin::class,
        'admin.guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAdmin::class,
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    ];
```

Middleware RedirectifNotAdmin.php controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfNotAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

my routes

```
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
```

Controller file
AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: try `Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->middleware(['auth:admin'])`

Comment: you can see:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270775/laravel-5-5-multi-authentication-routing-issue

Comment: @J.Doe try your code but not working.When i call /admin redirect to /login not /admin/login

Comment: add your admin middleware code to question

Comment: @J.Doe l'm edited question and added middleware.

Comment: RedirectIfNotAdmin::class add code if this class)

Comment: @J.Doe i'm added RedirectIfNotAdmin::class middleware code

Comment: i think that auth middleware run first, try add to RedirectIfNotAdmin class: `public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin')
    {
       dd('auth middleware')
        if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think here the auth middleware run first and for that reason you can not get your route url.

For solving issue you should add this logic inside `RedirectIfNotAdmin::class()`

My solution is :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = 'admin') 
{ 
    if(!Auth::guard($guard)->check())
    { 
        return redirect('admin/login'); 
    } 
    return $next($request);
}
```